# VB.Net Mouse.Enter and Mouse.Leave both called in same event?

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent, mouseenter, mouseleave

In my VB.Net forms application, I have a function:

```
Private Sub pnlMain_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlMain.MouseLeave
...
End Sub
```

and another function:

```
Private Sub pnlMain_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlMain.MouseEnter
...
End Sub
```

When the mouse enters or leaves both are executed - first Enter and then Leave.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you debugging the application?

Comment: Okay, hitting a breakpoint was one possibility, as John pointed out. The other possibility is that something within your `MouseEnter` code is causing something similar - but you haven't shown that code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't or it *shouldn't*

but if you have a breakpoint on the enter event then it will fire the mouseleave event as you hit it. (because you've triggered the leave event).

Comment: You are right, I didn't think of that.  However, it is happening even when not in debug mode.  It executes the code in both events.

Comment: I've got a proof of concept that doesn't do that.

Comment: @chiwda You need to be careful. Use logging to record when the events happen. Because otherwise the test reporting will trigger the leave event. E.g. If you bring up the debugger, show a message box... you will cause the Leave event